# Laravel powered search not working properly

Tags: laravel

I have 4 orders in my orders table that contain the word "green" somewhere within the name of the item ordered.

I am trying to make a search to get all order that contains "green" within its name.
But what i get is just one result.

Here is what i have tried.
  $orders = MyOrder::where('title', 'LIKE', '%green%')->get();

Comment: `where('name', 'LIKE', '%green%')` ?

Comment: what's not working properly?

Comment: already did this where('name', 'LIKE', '%green%') 
But its then its returning just one result instead of 4.

Comment: please, post how you are doing the query or what you tried.

Comment: Can you update your question with the query you tried, the expected results and the results you actually got?

Comment: use `->get()` instead of `->first()`

Comment: Well, the query looks good. If the field where the word "green" is in, is 'title' and not 'name', it should work. How are you checking that only one result returns?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "If the field where the word "green" is in, is 'title' and not 'name', it should work."

To answer your question i echo the returned order->id on my blade.
and it returns just one id.

Comment: Sorry, maybe for my poor english, but in the question before the update with the query, I thought that the field where you did the search was 'name' and not 'title'. So, the query will return a collection. Then, if I understand correctly, in blade you are doing a  `@foreach` and `echo $order->id`? Could you try with `dd($orders);` just after the query in the controller?

Comment: I tried it and it actually shows all the names that fits the search.
Now.. it seems the issue of from the blade or something. @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: yep, the search works. you're probably not showing the results correctly

Comment: I passed a collection of the order to my blade then looped through it with a foreach stmt..
I don't understand what i might be doing wrong.